# Dynamically buiding a grid with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been researching  how to dynamically construct a grid using jquery. I've read tons of api's and searched through s.o. and google but no one seems to give a clear overall stance on it. Maybe I'm just not understand also, so I'm using a function called build table and I want to return result.

So once this generate table button is clicked then it should display grid.

However nothing show

Can any one help

```
function buildTable(criteria)
{
  var result = new Object();
  result.rows = criteria.rows;
  result.totalRows = result.rows + 1;
  result.row = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i < result.rows; i++)
  {
    result.row[i] = new Object();
    result.row[i].shoeId = 100+i;
    result.row[i].dressId = "LKM0" + i;
    result.row[i].arrivalDt = "01/02/2013 15:45";
    result.row[i].stockDt = "01/02/2013 15:46";
    result.row[i].fashionStatus = "differences"; 
  }
  return result;
}
</script>   



<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick=" document.getElementById('Grid').style.visibility = 'visible';" />  

        <div class="Grid" id="Grid" onload="buildTable()" > </div>
```

Comment: Are you generating the data on the client side or the server side?

Comment: I'm generating the  data from a server side db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're generating the data on the server side, you could either render it when you render the page into your Grid div:

```
<div id="Grid" style="display:none">
    <table>
        ... etc ...
    </table>
</div>
```

and then just show the div when they click on the button

Or if you need to build up the table only when they click the button, then you could do so using Ajax:

```
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="loadGrid()" />

<script>
    $("#Grid").load("Url to generate table", function() {
         $(this).show();
    });
</script>
```

Or if you really want to build up the table using javascript, then [this might give you some ideas](http://jsfiddle.net/wLR6q/)

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm going to give this way a try. Thank you for the advice